# Multiple UICollectionView in one view update second UICollectionView data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to design as like image. I use two UICollectionView to design. But I can't update second UICollectionView data after click fast on UICollectionview row. I never think this is the correct way to do this. Any suggestion please. I need to do with Objective-C.

[image]

My Code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (view.tag == 1) {
        return 20;//SelfiThemeIm;age.count
    } else {
        return 15;
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cv.tag == 0) {
        TopCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TopCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: SelfiThemeImage[indexPath.row]]];
        cell.imageView.image  = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

        return cell;
    } else {
        BottomCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BottomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: SelfiThemePhysicalFileName[indexPath.row]]];
        cell.imageView.image  = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *ThemeURL;

    if (collectionView.tag == 1) {
        ThemeURL = @"http://wap.shabox.mobi/sticker_app_server/content.aspx?catid=";
        ThemeURL =[ThemeURL stringByAppendingString:[SelfiThemeImageContentCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        BottomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BottomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [manager GET:ThemeURL
          parameters:nil
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 NSString *array= [responseObject objectForKey:@"stickers"];

                 self.selfidata = array;

                 // NSLog(@"JSON responce Selfi: %@",     self.selfidata);

                 for(int i=0; i<=self.selfidata.count-1; i++){
                     NSString *PhysicalFileName = @"http://wap.shabox.mobi/CMS/content/graphics/Stickers/D200x200/";
                     PhysicalFileName =[PhysicalFileName stringByAppendingString:[[self.selfidata objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PhysicalFileName"]];
                     PhysicalFileName =[PhysicalFileName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];

                     [SelfiThemePhysicalFileName addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:PhysicalFileName]];
                     NSLog(@"PhysicalFileName Array - %@", PhysicalFileName);
                 }

                 NSLog(@"SelfiThemePhysicalFileName Array - %@", SelfiThemePhysicalFileName);

                 NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: SelfiThemePhysicalFileName[indexPath.row]]];
                 cell.imageView.image  = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             }];
    }else{
    }
}
```

Comment: Just reload second collectionview on didSelectItemAtIndexPath method and update your second collectionview data(array ) whatever and just reload it your problem solve it

Comment: Thanks for your replay sir, I am beginner, can you give me some sample code how to reload second UICollectionview with my code editing.

Comment: is there your item value fix ? for both collection with reload data ?

Comment: Not fixed at all. But I fail to set data when i test. so that I make it default.

Comment: if (view.tag == 1) {
        return 20;//SelfiThemeIm;age.count
    } else {
        return 15;
    } then why you write this code ?

Comment: if (view.tag == 1) { return SelfiThemeImage.count } else { return SelfiThemeImageDetails.count ; }  it looks like this.

Comment: NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: SelfiThemePhysicalFileName[indexPath.row]]];
                 cell.imageView.image  = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData]; dont do like this just simply here write collectionview.reloaddata()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129312/discussion-between-md-tariqul-islam-and-himanshu-moradiya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (view.tag == 1) {
        return SelfiThemeImage.count;
    } else {
        return SelfiThemePhysicalFileName.count;
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cv.tag == 0) {
        TopCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TopCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: SelfiThemeImage[indexPath.row]]];
        cell.imageView.image  = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

        return cell;
    } else {
        BottomCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BottomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: SelfiThemePhysicalFileName[indexPath.row]]];
        cell.imageView.image  = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *ThemeURL;

    if (collectionView.tag == 1) {
        ThemeURL = @"http://wap.shabox.mobi/sticker_app_server/content.aspx?catid=";
        ThemeURL =[ThemeURL stringByAppendingString:[SelfiThemeImageContentCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        BottomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BottomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [manager GET:ThemeURL
          parameters:nil
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 NSString *array= [responseObject objectForKey:@"stickers"];

                 self.selfidata = array;

                 // NSLog(@"JSON responce Selfi: %@",     self.selfidata);

                 for(int i=0; i<=self.selfidata.count-1; i++){
                     NSString *PhysicalFileName = @"http://wap.shabox.mobi/CMS/content/graphics/Stickers/D200x200/";
                     PhysicalFileName =[PhysicalFileName stringByAppendingString:[[self.selfidata objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PhysicalFileName"]];
                     PhysicalFileName =[PhysicalFileName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];

                     [SelfiThemePhysicalFileName addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:PhysicalFileName]];
                     NSLog(@"PhysicalFileName Array - %@", PhysicalFileName);
                 }

                 NSLog(@"SelfiThemePhysicalFileName Array - %@", SelfiThemePhysicalFileName);

                [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             }];
    }else{
    }
}
```

I made changes in your code that just replace it with your code .

Happy Coding. give vote and approve it

Thank You.

Comment: Where you find myCollectionView?

Comment: At that place put your collectionview i just give you one hit @Md.TariqulIslam

Comment: @Md.TariqulIslam is your problem solve then brother approve my answer

Comment: Brother I can't solve this still now. I am trying to solve

Comment: Your problem solve now just approve my answer and check your mail

Comment: Thank you so much to give support and solve my problem.

Comment: its my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

- You need have 2 objects referring `CollectioView`  lets say `_collectionView1` and `_collectionView1`.
- Now make sure delegate for these 2 is set to self
- in `-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` check

  ```
  if ([collectionView isEqualTo:_collectionView1]) {
      _collectionView2DataSource = ;//Do your calculation and setting
      [_collectionView2 reloadData] ;
  }
  ```

I am considering you have populated initial value and you are aware of all collection-view datasource and delegate functioning.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have the 2nd collectionview in storyboard/xib file, create the IBOUTLET for that collectionview and name it "what_ever_name_you_want"
2. if you have created this programatically, make the collectionview a global variable in the class
3. in didSelect method reload the collection view by calling `["what_ever_name_you_gave" reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this line because this line create new cell instance .

```
    BottomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BottomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

change with :

```
BottomCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```